# java.util.Timer

Tags: java, timer

```
if(e.getSource()==continuous)
{

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            rollthedice();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), 500);


}

    if(e.getSource()==stop)
    {

        timer.cancel();

    }
```

i hit the continuous button, rollthedice() executes looping twice a second, i hit the stop button rollthedice() stops, what i been looking for is a way to hit the continuous button again after i hit stop to start looping the rollthedice() method again, the stop is to stop the continuous cycle of rollthedice() but i want to be able to hit the continuous button again, idk how to do it, i been looking and looking

Updated thoughts:

```
Runnable runner = new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
        rollthedice();
    }
}

if(e.getSource()==continuous)
{
  future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
if(e.getSource()==stop)
{

    future .cancel();

}
```

Comment: Per hmjd's response, create a new `Timer` just before calling schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) instead. This will allow you to submit a task, cancel it and then submit again.

Comment: i tried this i got errors i made future the Timer, scheduler and TimeUnit cannot be resolved it says

Comment: All of those classes are part of the Java language. Did you forget to add the imports?

Comment: i cut out the Timer, runner is how it is above, scheduler is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, i have no future, and idk what to do to stop the scheduler, i new to this

Comment: Post what you now have. You don't stop the scheduler, you cancel the Future.

Comment: `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler;
 scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
 
 Runnable runner = new Runnable(){
     public void run()
     {
         rollthedice();
     }
 };
 
 
 if(e.getSource()==continuous)
 {
  
  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 }
 if(e.getSource()==stop)
 {

    scheduler.shutdown();

 }` i want the stop button to stop the scheduler and then when i click continuous to start it again

Comment: Notice that `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate` returned a `ScheduledFuture` which implement `cancel`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable, long, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: i dont exactly know how to use it

Comment: im a beginner trying to get into practice you know

Comment: actually if you dont wana even bother i just downloaded the training off oracle and it has the whole section in tutorials so i can just go through it, thanks for your time

Comment: @JRowan I had asked you to update your question not my answer. It is not really appropriate for you to put a guess of a solution into my answer since it make it look like I posted it. It is one thing to edit (format, etc) a thought that someone else posted, but to add a whole block of code into someone else's post is something else. I moved your code to your question.

Answer (score 2):

From the javadoc for [`Timer.cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29):

> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists). Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.

This means a new instance of `Timer` will be required to execute `rollthedice()` method again.

Comment: what is a way to make a new instance for the loop